# Добавить кнопку в CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

Как добавить в CKEditor кнопку, выделяющую текст заголовком `h6`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957156/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-the-toolbar-that-calls-a-javascript-function

Comment: Насколько я понял, код плагина должен использовать функцию `CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element.wrapWith`? Нигде не нашел информацию о ней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nup, посмотрите пример:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'codeH6', {
  icons: 'h6',
  init: function( editor ) {
    editor.addCommand( 'wrapH6', {
      exec: function( editor ) {
        editor.insertHtml( '<h6>' + editor.getSelection().getSelectedText() + '</h6>' );
      }
    });
    editor.ui.addButton( 'H6Button', {
      label: 'Wrap H6',
      command: 'wrapH6',
      toolbar: 'insert'
    });
  }
});
```

иконка должна быть в папке `icons` в формате `png`, прим: `../plugins/codeH6/icons/h6.png`
Название файла со скриптом должно быть `plugin.js`

И в `config.js`: `config.extraPlugins = 'codeH6';`